# face recognition using AVfoundation with image as a source file

Tags: ios, avfoundation, face-recognition, avcapturedevice

I want to use AVFoundation to perform face recognition on an image taken from the camera roll. 
Is this possible, in the first place?

I've found many tutorials on how to do this using live camera stream as input. I studied them and found no way to bind an AVCaptureInputDevice to an image.

P.S.
I don't want to use CoreImage. Actually I want to ditch CoreImage and use AVFoundation face recognition.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with CoreImage? It uses the same detector:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."];
CIImage *img = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url]; // uiImageObj.CIImage
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
NSDictionary *detectorOptions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:CIDetectorAccuracyLow, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];
CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:context options:detectorOptions];
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:img];
```

Comment: Hi @peter, thank you for your answer but, as I pointed out in my question, I already know how to use CoreImage face detection. I noticed that CI doesn't recognizes faces that are rotated 45 or more degrees (e.g. upside down), while is seems that AVFoundation does. So I'm not sure it is the exact same detector...